# Python - Define new arrays or variables without having to Predefine them

Tags: python, arrays, eval

```
n = input(': ')

eval('Array'+n)=[]
```

I figured It'd be something like this but this just yields - 'Can't assign to function call', any help? If it's possible, that is...

Comment: If you think you need this, you're doing something else wrong in your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please describe your _actual_ problem, not how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: You *can* do something like this by modifying `globals()`, but you really *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
arrays = {}
n = input(': ')
arrays['Array%s' % n] = []
```

Comment: Or probably a `list`, given he's trying to create a dynamic array.  But yeah.

Comment: @sr2222 - A list of lists will only work if he's ensuring numeric keys - a dict lets you use arbitrary keys, was my may reason for suggesting it.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see.  Took me a bit to dig my way through what the OP was trying to do.